# Spring stackoverflow exception

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am having XML Based spring configuration Rest API project. It is deployed on apache tomcat using java 7 version. It started throwing exception. Code sample is :

```
for (TempDTO tempDTO : finalTempDTO.getData()) {
            Integer candidateId = tempDTO.getId();
            logger.info("--------------------------------------------");
            logger.info("id: " + candidateId);
            if(!candidateAlreadyInserted(candidateId)) {
                if (!tempUtil.isEmpty(tempDTO.getOccupation())) {
                    occupation = tempDTO.getOccupation().replaceAll("(?s)<[^>]*>(\\s*<[^>]*>)*", " ").trim();
                }
                if (!tempUtil.isEmpty(tempDTO.getDescription())) {
                    description = tempDTO.getDescription().replaceAll("(?s)<[^>]*>(\\s*<[^>]*>)*", " ").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\\\.]+", " ").replace("\\n", " ").trim();
                }
                DataEntity dataEntity = new DataEntity();
                dataEntity.setBhCandidateId(candidateId);
                dataEntity.setDescription(description);
                dataEntity.setOccupation(occupation);
                dataRepository.save(dataEntity);
            }
            logger.info("--------------------------------------------");
        }
```

When I execute the request, it throws Exception:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1303)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:118)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

Root Cause:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
>       java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)

Comment: tempDTO.getDescription() = what you are getting here?

Comment: html data for which I am using replaceAll to remove tags

Comment: Sorry, I can't but I got the problem. String size is greater than allowed. I am not getting how to handle this problem. It throws compilation exception: java constant string too long.

Comment: Can't you replace part by part...do substring till it supports and then replace...

Comment: To replace or to get substring, it need to a string. At the time of assignment, it htrows compilation error

Comment: If it's not a string than how can u use replace all...ur get description() should give string...take that and do substring and then use pattern for that..